# Using Twitters API in Android with a Parse.com backend

Tags: android, twitter, parse-platform

I am trying to use Parse.com on my Android Application to authenticate my users with Twitter.

Basically, I have a 'Register with Twitter' button. When the user presses this, the Twitter dialog opens, and he signs up. Here is the onClick() function for the Register With Twitter button:

```
public void registerTwitter(View view)
{
    ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(this, new LogInCallback() {
          @Override
          public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
            if (user == null) {
                               //do something else, User quit the dialog
            } 
            else if (user.isNew()) 
            {
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } 
            else 
            {
                //User already exists, do something else
            }
          }
        });
}
```

Here, the code is working, and there is a ParseUser being created in the back as intended. However, the problem is: how do I get the other public data from the Twitter API to add to my ParseUser object? Like First Name, Last Name, Image, Email etc?

All I get at the backend is a number in the 'Username' field, and the authData object from Twitter

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: What error are you getting in logcat just after it crashes? Logcat should always be your starting point for trying to diagnose a run-time error. In fact, if you read the stack of errors and just try to understand it, you'll probably be able to fix the error yourself 90% of the time by going to the line number the log points to into the file names that sound familiar to you because they're part of your project. As to the rest of your question, I can't really answer it since I'm not familiar enough with parse.com

Comment: Actually, I was able to fix the crash. The main problem is getting the data from the Twitter API

Answer (score 2):

```js
TwitterInfo twitterInfo = null;
  Twitter twitter = ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter();
  String twitterUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=" + twitter.getUserId();

  HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(twitterUrl);
  twitter.signRequest(request);

  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

  try
  {
   HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
   BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

   String result = input.readLine();
   Log.d(TAG, "getTwitterInfo: result=" + result);

   JSONObject JsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);

   String profileImageUrl = JsonResponse.getString("profile_image_url");
   String fullName = JsonResponse.getString("name");

   twitterInfo = new TwitterInfo(fullName, profileImageUrl);

   return twitterInfo;

  }
  catch(ClientProtocolException e)
  {
   throw new CamoPhotoException(e.getMessage());
  }
  catch(IOException e)
  {
   throw new CamoPhotoException(e.getMessage());

  }
  catch(JSONException e)
  {
   throw new CamoPhotoException(e.getMessage());

  }
```